# Java Pattern.matches

Tags: java, regex

Pattern.matches("[A(BC)]", "BC") why this returns false?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that regex doesn't do what you think it does. You may want to read [learning regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions).

Answer (score 2):

Because the pattern expects to see a **single** character from the class `A(BC)`, and [`matches`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches-java.lang.String-java.lang.CharSequence-) matches the entire input against the regex (doesn't look for partial matches). Since the input is two characters, it isn't a match.

Comment: Circe bracket doesn't group BC to the 'single character'?

Comment: @lukhol: No. `(` and `)` have no special meaning within a character class (`[...]`). *Outside* of one, they form a capture group, but it's a capture group that would capture `BC`, not *either* `B` or `C`. I suggest stepping back from your current task and working through some basic Java regular expression tutorials.